# How to sync an online git master branch

Tags: git, github

I have a linux (debian) machine. I need to keep a local folder synchronized with an online git master branch. What is the simple and correct way to do it?

Currently I run "git clone xxx.git ./folder". And every time when I need an update, I delete the local folder and run the clone command again. However, the folder is pretty big so it takes time to clone again. I guess there must be a simple way to "synchronize" instead of "delete and download again".

BTW, it is nothing about uploading or modifying the master branch. I just want to download the most updated version of the content.

Answer (score 2):

a `git pull origin master` should work

Best,

Nik

Comment: Hi Nik, is the complete command `git pull origin master xxx.git ./folder`? thanks.

Comment: I believe that since you are already cloning just that specific directory that it should update without having to add `xxx.git ./folder`. I personally just clone the whole repository and not specific directories but I hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` should do what you want.

Side note: If you do decide you need to modify it, you can use `git commit "Comments" file` which will commit to your local machine and then `git push` which will update the repository.

Comment: so the complete command is `git pull xxx.git ./folder`, right? thanks.

Comment: Just cd to ./folder and then git pull. That should be all you need.